# Unstable run in SharePoint Framework Extension

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I have deployed a SPFx Extension solution to my site.

Everything went well except the Extension sometime loads, sometimes doesn't. In another word, if I refresh it a few times then sometime it won't work.

All I got in the browser console when it doesn't work is:

```
Failed to create application customizer 'ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer.6998cb93-00a1-46a6-a00b-786fd612c706'. Error information is '***Manifest not found for componentId "6998cb93-00a1-46a6-a00b-786fd612c706".'
```

I know the manifest is there since it's working with some refresh. The scripts are deployed into our CDN in the same site collection.

[image]

Elements:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">    
<!-- Custom Action -->
<CustomAction 
    Title="SpFxTermsConditionsApplicationCustomizer"
    Location="ClientSideExtension.ApplicationCustomizer"
    ClientSideComponentId="6998cb93-00a1-46a6-a00b-786fd612c706"
    ClientSideComponentProperties="{&quot;Top&quot;:&quot;Top area of the page&quot;,&quot;Bottom&quot;:&quot;Bottom area in the page&quot;}">
</CustomAction>
<!-- End Custom Action -->
```

Can someone know what cause this ?
Thanks,

Comment: make sure you have the correct versions of tools. This was a bug a while back but has been fixed: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/632

Comment: can you also share the `elements.xml` file ? Did you reference that file correctly in the ` package-solution.json` file ?

Comment: @AliJafer: I'm running latest SPFx 1.3 but I'll check tmr to see if it's updated or anything else is outdated.

Comment: @GautamSheth: I will post it tmr. But if it's incorrect then it shouldn't work at all. Not like this. This is weird T_T

Comment: @AliJafer: I updated the @types/sharepoint to latest version and things seem to work normally again (the types was update 3 days ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update @types/sharepoint into 2016.0.0 fix it.